# Selecting aggregated string from database

Tags: postgresql, c#

I have a table in my database consisting of one column which is `NewLanguage(varchar)`. I insert new languages to the table and I want to select the rows of the table and assign them to a string variable delimited by ','. I try to select the languages as in the code:

```
    public string  SelectLanguagesFromDatabase()
    {
        try
        {
           NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(
             "SELECT string_agg(\"NewLanguage\",',') FROM \"Languages\")", 
             dbConnection);

           results = (string) command.ExecuteScalar();
           command.Prepare();
        }
         catch( Exception ex){
             MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString() );
         }
        return results;
    }
```

When I test it, `results` returns as `null`. I want to take string representation of the rows's values separated by ','. How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: ... and if you run it by hand with `psql` or PgAdmin-III or whatever, what do you see?

Comment: There aren't any parentheses in the query in the comment. Please *edit the original question* and copy and paste the exact query + error there, so it's readable.

Comment: @CraigRinger Sorry, i run it in pgadmin-III and it works correctly.I think my problem is i can't take the result of select and assign it to results.

Comment: Yeah, you can't just cast a resultset to string. See the nPgSQL documentation for details.